# html.html.twig Template Name for content type

Tags: theming

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions gives the example of html--node--[nodeid].html.twig for an individual node - what template name can I use for html.html.twig for a content type such as Article?

Comment: Try enabling debugging and check the template names that get printed: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own theme suggestions. If you want to create a custom suggestion for `html.html.twig`, you need to use the hook `hook_theme_suggestion_html_alter`.

in your `theme_name.theme` file add the following function:

```
function theme_name_theme_suggestion_html_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'html__' . $node->bundle();
}
```